What is the usecase for abstract interface class in Dart language
I'm just trying to learn darts, and it's difficult for me. It's a different keyword in other languages.
What is the use case of abstract interface class?
void main() {
  var reader = Reader();
  reader.read();

  var reader2 = Reader2();
  reader2.read();
}

abstract interface class Readable {
  void read() {
    print('read abc...');
  }
}

class Reader implements Readable {
  @override
  void read() {
    print('Reading...');
  }
}

class Reader2 extends Readable {
  @override
  void read() {
    print('Read something...');
  }
}


abstract interface class Readable {} is the equivalent of public interface Readable {} in say Java or C#. See also https://dart.dev/language/class-modifiers#interface
